# Case sort by A-Z Ascending and 0-9 Descending?

Tags: php, sorting

I have image arrays such as

```
    [Images] => Array
        (
            [0] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10396-alt-1.jpg
            [1] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10396-main-599.jpg
        )

    [Images] => Array
        (
            [0] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/category/10167-main-354.jpg
            [1] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10167-alt-1.jpg
            [2] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10167-alt-2.jpg
            [3] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/category/10168-main-361.jpg
            [4] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/category/10168-main-360.jpg
        )
```

That I would like to sort by basename, but also by alphanum in a specific way

I would always like the first 5 digits to be sorted by numerically after having the alpha sorted ascending (z-a) then also have the last digits sorted descending. How would I accomplish this?

Sample output should be like this

```
    [Images] => Array
        (
            [0] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10396-main-599.jpg
            [1] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10396-alt-1.jpg
        )

    [Images] => Array
        (
            [0] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/category/10167-main-354.jpg
            [1] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/category/10168-main-360.jpg
            [2] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/category/10168-main-361.jpg
            [3] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10167-alt-1.jpg
            [4] => /var/www/httpdocs/images/products/detail/10167-alt-2.jpg
        )
```

Comment: Can you provide an example of the wanted outcome please?

Comment: Yep hold on and I'll provide an outcome and a more in-depth array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. Extract filename from path: `10396-main-599`
2. Split filename with '-' as a separator `10396`,`main`,`599`
3. Sort path using comparison function

   ```
   function is_path_less($split_path1,$split_path2){
     if($split_path1[0] == $split_path2[0]){
       if($split_path1[1] == $split_path2[1]){
         return $split_path1[2] < $split_path2[2];
       }else{
         return $split_path1[1] > $split_path2[1];
       }
     }else{
       return $split_path1[0] < $split_path2[0];
     }
   }
   ```

Where `$split_path1` and `$split_path2` are ["10396","main","599"] and ["10396","alt","1"]

The result will be:

```
["10396","main","599"]
["10396","alt","1"]
```